# How to initialize static final variables based on cmd args?

Tags: java, static, command-line-arguments, final

Coursework brief requires me to assign an optional cmd argument to a static final variable.

I have tried doing it in main() but compiler complains "cannot assign a value to final variable". I've tried doing it in a static method called by main() but same error. I've heard about static blocks being used in other answers but I need to be able to reach cmd args when I decide what to assign. I've also got some headaches over argument parsing as both arguments should have default values unless one is provided. Any bonus advice is very welcome.

```java
public class FibonacciNim {
    private static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final int NO_OF_HEAPS;
    private static final int TOKENS_PER_HEAP;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set heaps and tokens using args
        if (args.length == 0) {
            NO_OF_HEAPS = 3;
            TOKENS_PER_HEAP = 9;
        } else {
            boolean usageCorrect = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length-1; i++) {
                if (args[i].equals("-heaps")) {
                    try {
                        NO_OF_HEAPS = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]));
                        usageCorrect = true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        usageCorrect = false;
                    }
                } else if (args[i].equals("-tokens")) {
                    try {
                        TOKENS_PER_HEAP = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
                        usageCorrect = true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        usageCorrect = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Does the static variable really need to be final?

Comment: Hey looks like a good question! welcome! so final could be a pre-used Keyword in Java, also you can try define these variables INSIDE main, because they look out of scope here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't...actually, really assign something from the command line to a static final variable.  (You might be able to by extremely dirty hackery, but this is probably not the intent of the assignment.)

What might be possible is that you're supposed to create a mutable static final and assign it to the contents of that.  That's terrible practice and you really shouldn't do it in real life, but it's at least plausible.  For example, you might write

```
static final String[] argHolder = new String[1];
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
  argsHolder[0] = args[0];
  ...
}
```

Comment: I like this idea except that my brief says:
"It should be possible to change the number of heaps of tokens in your program by only changing one or more static variables"

Comment: In that case, you should be making static variables that are not final.

Comment: Or can make them into mutable static final variables.

Comment: Meant to type "one or more static final variables".

Comment: That's...extraordinarily weird.  I don't think there's any other way besides the way I described to make that work.

Comment: Changed accepted answer to this because feedback from my professor said that this was what he expected.

Comment: If your professor cant accepted alternate correct answers then hes not a good professor. Using Mutable objects over a string array makes the code more maintainable as anyone who reads your code after you would know what the variables are for much easier than trying to figure out what the array is used for

Answer (score 4):

Static Final variables can only be assigned at initialization.

```
public class MyClass {

  private static final int NO_OF_HEAPS = 3;

}
```

Non-static final variables can be assigned in line or in the constructor:

```
public class MyClass {

  private final int NO_OF_HEAPS;

  public MyClass() {
    NO_OF_HEAPS = 9;
  }

}
```

You could; however, set your static variables to "essentially" final by changing them to a mutable item such as an `AtomicInteger`

```
public class FibonacciNim {
  private static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static final AtomicInteger NO_OF_HEAPS = new AtomicInteger(0);
  private static final AtomicInteger TOKENS_PER_HEAP = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set heaps and tokens using args
    if (args.length == 0) {
        NO_OF_HEAPS.set(3);
        TOKENS_PER_HEAP.set(3);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

As far as parsing command line arguments you can check out `JCommander` http://jcommander.org/

It provides functionality to parse command line arguments and populate a POJO to use so you do not have to parse them yourself.

Comment: I opted for this choice but my professor's feedback said that he believes AtomicInteger's are intended for threading-related work.

Comment: Technically he is correct that is normally what they are used for but it doesn't mean they can only be used for that. As described if you need a static final mutable object, you'd need something like `AtomicInteger` as `int` and `Integer` are immutable objects.